# Grooviest way in Gradle to list subdirectories matching a certain pattern

Tags: gradle, groovy, build.gradle

In my Gradle script, I would like to include directories matching a certain pattern in my source set. I need to search and scan for all subdirectories and include all subdirectories:

1. Any second level directories that have Java or Groovy files in them (could be deeply nested inside the package folder structure).
2. And/or any sub/directories that have a certain name e.g. `api` or `source`

The problem is that `srcDirs` under `java sourceSet` only accepts directories and not files.

What I've tried so far:

```
def javaSourceDirs = []
project.rootDir.eachFileRecurse(FileType.DIRECTORIES) { file ->
    if ((file.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("api") || file.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("sources")))
        javaSourceDirs << file
}
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs = javaSourceDirs
        };
    }
}
```

Just wondering if there's a better/cleaner way using `fileTree` or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
def findAllUnder = { File f, String fileOrDir, String pattern ->
    def result = [ ]
    def recursiveCall
    switch ( fileOrDir ) {
        case 'file': recursiveCall = f.&eachFileRecurse
            break
        case 'dir': recursiveCall = f.&eachDirRecurse
            break
        default: throw new RuntimeException( "Must be file or dir: $fileOrDir" )
    }

    recursiveCall { File path -> if ( path.name ==~ pattern ) result << path }

    return result
}

def hasSources = { File f -> f.directory && findAllUnder( f, 'file', /.*\.(groovy|java)/ ) }

def sourceDirs = findAllUnder( project.rootDir, 'dir', '(?i)api|sources' ).findAll( hasSources )
```

It will return a `List<File>` with all dirs matching the names `api` or `sources` (case-insensitive) which have at least one groovy or java file under it.

It does not check for nested dirs, so if you're unlucky and have a dir with sources called `groovy/api/com/api/`, both `groovy/api` and `groovy/api/com/api` will be returned.